# javascript onclick behavior in Firefox and Safari different?

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, onclick, submit

I'm debugging an issue and found strange behavior in how Firefox and Safari deal with the onclick JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="createMessageForm" action="onclick.php?refresh=<?php echo ++$_REQUEST['refresh'];?>" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" id="iteration" value="1"/>
</form>
<a href="page2.html" target="_blank" onclick="document.getElementById('createMessageForm').submit();return true;">Hello</a>
```

Loading this in Firefox, it always opens 'page2' for me. But loading this in Safari, it only open the 'page2' for me about 1 in 10 times, or less. It's like depends on whether the browser can finish the 'return true;' statement before the form got submitted or not.

I thought JavaScript is always single-threaded, so what's the expected behavior in such code?

Comment: That code inherently has undefined behavior. You're setting up a race between two HTTP requests.

Comment: Pointy: Please see my comment responding to camus below.  So does that mean Javascript would actually spawn out another HTTP request for the form-submit while still trying to finish what it is doing in the current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is single-threaded as you say. However it is also happy to work asynchronously.

HTTP requests are async events in javascript because they can take an unknown amount of time to complete. Javascript makes the call to the HTTP request and then carries on with whatever else it has to do until the HTTP request completes and returns control back to Javascript (or in this case, completes and triggers the browser to load the new page).

In your case, you're basically firing two HTTP requests from Javascript, one right after the other. The second is fired because Javascript doesn't wait for the first to respond; it just carries on to the next one. The unpredictable results you're seeing are basically the result of whichever of the two HTTP requests completes its response first, to the point of getting the browser to load the new page.

This is also how AJAX works -- the 'A' in AJAX stands for Asynchronous. Javascript makes the HTTP request, and will happily carry on doing whatever else you want of it. The HTTP request is handled by the browser, which triggers an event for Javascript to pick up when the request is ready. That's why with AJAX calls you need to give it a 'success' function, rather than just saying `if(success)` in the next line of code.

And that leads me to a suggestion to solve your problem. Fire the form submission as an AJAX event. That way, the browser will never try to load it as a new page when it responds. You can still tell the browser to trigger the separate page load immediately afterwards if you like, although I would suggest waiting for the first call to finish, as otherwise you won't know whether it has actually succeeded.

Hope that gives you some help.

Comment: Right on!  Exact explanation I was looking for!  Yes to your suggestion as well.  That's exactly what I plan to 'fix' it.  But was trying to see if there is a 5 second dirty fix I can do for this problem as it's a production issue.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Make php **redirect** to page2 once the form is submitted and processed serverside  inside the onclick.php , there is no reason whatsoever to do what you are doing , at least the code you wrote doesnt show any reason to do it.

i quote it :

```
<form id="createMessageForm" action="onclick.php?refresh=<?php echo ++$_REQUEST['refresh'];?>" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" id="iteration" value="1"/>
</form>
<a href="page2.html" target="_blank" onclick="document.getElementById('createMessageForm').submit();return true;">Hello</a>
```

Comment: I'm extracting some piece of code out to showcase what's going on (in the application that I'm debugging).  The application logic design itself is definitely flawed.  I'm just trying to find out what's the behavior of Javascript when such case happen.  i.e. when a form-submit happen in the middle of javascript code, would it wait until all the rest of javascript within current page is done before moving on to the form-submit?  Or does it behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

whats your question here? its basically what Pointy said. depends on the browser implementation.

if your question is how to fix it just change

```
return true; into -> return false;
```

in your link